# JSP/JSTL change value member of array

Tags: arrays, spring, jstl

I want to change  a value of array in JSP/JSTL which are created in controller. How can I do?

```
if(_shop_commisions!=null)
    {
        double[] _sum = new double[6];
        model.addAttribute("sum",_sum);
    }
```

JSTL

```
<c:set var="sum[0]" value="4"  />    
${sum[0]} // It has to show 4.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You´re setting a variable with name "sum[0]" and value 4 
If you want to change the model you have to interact with the model.

```
          ${sum[0]=4}
```

Comment: '<c:set var="sum[0]" value="4"  /> ' It was my solution, but it didn't work. I'm looking for better and correct solution.

Comment: Do you understand my response?. I said that your solution is not correct. You have to try what I wrote you down

Comment: Yes, I do. I tried like this  `${sum[0]=="4"}` `<c:out value="${sum[0]}"  /> ` Result: false, and 0.0

Comment: ups sorry I put an extra = look now my answer

Comment: I guess is the same, but did you try with <% sum[0]=4%>

Comment: javax.el.ELException: Failed to parse the expression [${sum[0]="4"}]
 org.apache.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.createNodeInternal(ExpressionBuilder.java:145)
 org.apache.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.build(ExpressionBuilder.java:171)

Comment: And this? ${sum[0]=4}

Comment: no more ideas buddy, mark your solution if you find it

Comment: can you add the solution in your question please